# Bulma: Responsive buttons and spacing helpers are missing

Tags: bulma, responsiveness

I know the classes which I can add to tags, but how to do it responsive? For example, I want to reduce the button size on mobiles. How can I do that with Bulma? I would like to use something readily available, for instance classes `is-small` or `is-medium`, instead style each parameter in a standard way.

In the example below, I would like to reduce the size of the buttons in mobile. I enclose simple gallery with buttons styled by Bulma's class `is-primary`.

By the way, is there any option to add margin or padding directly by Bulma (like in Bootstrap)? I didn't find it in the docs.

```js
function show(index) {
  document
    .querySelectorAll(".custom-image")
    .forEach(item => (item.style.display = "none"));

  document.querySelectorAll(".custom-image")[index].style.display =
    "block";
}
document.querySelectorAll(".custom-image")[0].style.display = "block";
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: grey;
}

body .box {
  max-width: 70vw;
  box-shadow: 26px 25px 55px -4px #413e41;
}

body .box:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

body .custom-image {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

body button:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css" />

<div class="box">
  <div class="custom-image ">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/01/22/02/mountain-landscape-2031539_960_720.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="custom-image">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/10/02/23/03/dawn-190055_960_720.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="custom-image">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/12/29/23/49/rays-3902368_960_720.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <button onclick="show(0)" class="button is-primary ">1</button>
  <button onclick="show(1)" class="button is-primary ">2</button>
  <button onclick="show(2)" class="button is-primary ">3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Responsive buttons are not implemented in Bulma. But you can do something like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .button.is-small-mobile {
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: .75rem
  }
}
```

```js
function show(index) {
  document
    .querySelectorAll(".custom-image")
    .forEach(item => (item.style.display = "none"));
  document.querySelectorAll(".custom-image")[index].style.display =
    "block";
}
document.querySelectorAll(".custom-image")[0].style.display = "block";
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: grey;
}

body .box {
  max-width: 70vw;
  box-shadow: 26px 25px 55px -4px #413e41;
}

body .box:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

body .custom-image {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

body button:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .button.is-small-mobile {
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: .75rem
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css">
<div class="box">
  <div class="custom-image ">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/01/22/02/mountain-landscape-2031539_960_720.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="custom-image">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/10/02/23/03/dawn-190055_960_720.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="custom-image">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/12/29/23/49/rays-3902368_960_720.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <button onclick="show(0)" class="button is-primary is-small-mobile">1</button>
  <button onclick="show(1)" class="button is-primary is-small-mobile">2</button>
  <button onclick="show(2)" class="button is-primary is-small-mobile">3</button>
</div>
```

There are no helpers that add margin or padding. The developer of Bulma doesn't want to bloat Bulma with helpers.
https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/451

But there is a library `bulma-helpers`:

https://github.com/jmaczan/bulma-helpers#padding-for-one-side

Answer (score 0):

I addition to the great library that user3589620 pointed out, I would like to add that Bulma by now has some spacing helpers (not responsive by viewport witdth though): See https://bulma.io/documentation/helpers/spacing-helpers/

From their examples:

```
<!-- Adds 1rem of margin at the bottom -->
<p class="mb-4">
  Margin bottom
</p>

<!-- Adds 0.25rem of padding on the left and the right -->
<p class="px-1">
  Horizontal padding
</p>

<!-- Removes the margin on the right and adds 0.75rem padding at the top -->
<p class="mr-0 pt-3">
  Both
</p>
```